# Which is the best EJB container for learning EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm planning to dive into EJB so I'm looking for a simple EJB container.

Advantages:

- Eclipse plugin
- zero install
- good community support (forum, blog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glassfish would be a good choice. Especially since its a relatively small download, starts up really fast and is always up to date with the Java EE specifications.

JBoss AS isn't really that bad either. It's also free, but is a somewhat larger download, starts up slower and not being the reference implementation means its always a little behind Glassfish. Although the Java EE edition of Eclipse bundles a WTP adaptor for JBoss AS, you'd be better off installing the separate adaptor from JBoss tools if you want incremental deployment.

I did find the JBoss community to be really helpful, especially the EJB and overall JBoss AS communities (via the JBoss forum).

Comment: I've downlloaded JBoss AS 6. It was easy to integrate to Eclipse (only with WTP adaptor) and I made the first EBJ. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd sugest you GlassFish AS. It is free and also has full implementation of the Java EE spec.

Answer (score 0):

depends on your desired path:

Glassfish IS the reference implementation that all other containers are measured against with respect to the EE standard spec.

JBoss/Wildfly is the defacto standard, as there are a vast majority of sites leveraging it

WebSphere is the defacto standard in "licensed environments", meaning big corporations willing to pay for support.

TBH, choosing any container to learn on is fine.  i would caution you to not stop at one, though.  pick two or three and familiarize yourself with how they differ, because that will ultimately drive your future paths.

https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/04/top-10-open-source-java-and-javaee-application-servers/